# Why define two sigma algebra? [Papa Rudin - Riez Representation Theorem]

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

[image]

I have been really puzzled as to why he would require the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathfrak{M}$. What significances does $E\cap K\in \mathfrak{M}_F$ for all compact sets, have?

Comment: You can't expect such a $\mu$ to be a measure on all subsets of X. The sigma-algebra defined first are the finite measure sets with "inner regularity". This property is really too strong, if only because we would like to talk about infinite measure sets. So the second sigma-algebra consists of sets that "locally" satisfy inner regularity. It may help to think about all of this in the concrete context of the Lebesgue measure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the measure 
$$\delta_{\mathbb Z}:= \sum_{z \in \mathbb Z} \delta_z$$

Then, $\mathbb R \notin \mathfrak{M}_F$, which is a problem. But, you do have $\mathbb R \in \mathfrak{M}$.

Also, most importantly,  **$\mathfrak{M}_F$ is not a $\sigma$-algebra** in this case, as $[n,n+1] \in \mathfrak{M}_F$ but $\bigcup_n [n,n+1] \notin \mathfrak{M}_F$. In general, $\mathfrak{M}_F$ is a $\sigma$-algebra only if the measure is finite (in which case you have $\mathfrak{M}_F=\mathfrak{M}$).

$\mathfrak{M}$ is always a $\sigma$-algebra, and it is the right object,but it is hard to define it directly, without referring first to $\mathfrak{M}_F$.

Comment: Must we require that $E\cap K\in \mathfrak{M}_F$ for all **compact** sets $K$? Is this done for convience or is this the weakest condition you can set to make $\mathfrak{M}_F$ "work properly"?

Comment: @user160110 You want your measure to be regular. For this to happen, all measurable precompact sets must have finite measure, which is exactly that condition.